# Assigning values to an element

Tags: javascript, dom, variables, object, element

I was wondering if it was possible to assign values to an element object. In this case, I wish to assign the returns from the `setTimeout()` function to an object within an element object.

For example:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('target');
elem.timeouts = new Object();
elem.timeouts.sometimeout = setTimeout('...', 1000);
```

So I could then do:

```
clearTimeout(elem.timeouts.sometimeout);
```

I know this might seem bad practice etc, but is it possible or will it cause browsers to catch fire and turn on their user etc.

Thanks.

Comment: I usually tack a $ in front of stuff like this just to avoid overwriting a DOM property. Actually, 'usually' is a bad choice of words. Revision: The few times I've done this I added a $.

Comment: So you precede the name of the object that stores the returns with a $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM elements are *Host objects* (aka *non-native*) and as such they can do almost anything they want. It's not guaranteed that your expandos will work. In particular IE used to have problems with them. It's highly recommended to read this article:

**[What’s wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) *by @kangax***
 *(it is from one of the Prototype.js developers who experienced the drawbacks of such bad habits. They've rewritten the whole library just to save themselfs from more headaches)*

Now if you add `uniqueID` to elements in non-IE browsers (IE has it by default) and then your `data` function becomes a simple **lookup** ~ O(1). The real information will be stored in a *closure*.

It's **2-4x faster** than `jQuery.data` **([test](http://jsperf.com/data-storage/3))**

```
data(elem, "key", "value");
```

**1.) Hash table**

```
var data = (function () {
    var storage = {};
    var counter = 1;
    return function (el, key, value) {
        var uid = el.uniqueID || (el.uniqueID = counter++);
        if (typeof value != "undefined") {
            storage[uid] || (storage[uid] = {});
            storage[uid][key] = value; // set
        } else if (storage[uid]) {
            return storage[uid][key]; // get
        }
    };
})();
```

**2.) Array**

If you want to avoid expandos all together you can use an array to hold elements (but it's slower)

```
var data = (function () {
    var elements = [];
    var storage = [];
    return function (el, key, value) {
        var i = elements.indexOf(el);
        if (typeof value != "undefined") {
            if (i == -1) {
                i = elements.length;
                elements[i] = el;
                storage[i] = {};
            }
            storage[i][key] = value; // set
        } else if (storage[i]) {
            return storage[i][key]; // get
        }
    };
})();
```

**Array.prototype.indexOf** (fallback)

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (item) {
        var len = this.length >>> 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (this[i] === item) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    };
}
```

You're welcome! :)

Comment: So you are still extending the dom, just not as much, by placing a unique ID within the element.

Comment: I consider `uniqueID` an upcoming feature in browsers, which will eventually be copied from IE (as happened to many many things before). So this is something similar to conditionally adding `Array.prototype.indexOf` for browsers not yet supporting it. Also, non-IE browsers behave nicely in this case. If you don't want to touch the DOM completely you can use *version 2*. This is the very reason I've included it in my answer. The whole topic is too complex to address everything in the remaining 80 charecters. :)

Comment: Wow, for the first time ever there is something that IE has that I wish the rest had! I will settle for arrays, I will just write some kind of storage function to interface with it and use that for it. Thank you for your input, this has been extremely helpful!

Comment: But if you read through the article you can see that **conditionally  adding a single `uniqueID` doesn't suffer** from the many downsides mentioned (*Chance of collisions, Performance overhead, Browser bugs*)

Comment: @Wolfy, `innerHTML`, `clientHeight/Width`, `getBoundingClientRect()` the whole model is from IE, and I could go on.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, DOM elements retrieved by JS, are JS variables :) ..BTW it's not a common practice do that stuff in that way. I think the answer of [@galambalazs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/378024/galambalazs) is more deep and complete ;)

Comment: Well I am looking to store animations timeouts in there so I can have a function to clear an elements animations, do you think there is a better way other than assigning data to the actual object?

Comment: you could create an object that stores the timeouts and for example for each element it 'saves' its current timeout..

Comment: I just tested it in jsFiddle and it worked just how I wanted. You answered first so thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. However, if you're using some frameworks (e.g. mootools, jQuery) they provide storing methods by hashing the thing you want to store with a string and it's useful if you want obtain this without the risk to overwrite some default element props ;)

Comment: -1 I'm sorry but it's considered a bad advice. http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/ - also included in my answer

Comment: No problem ;) I obv accept the -1! This is the way we can learn from each other.. I didn't know about it ;)

Comment: The general problem is not the information you've given (*"It's possible"*), but the suggeston (*"you can store whatever you want"*). If you rephrase a bit I'll undo the vote :)

Comment: Sure, I understand the problem and I rephrase it :) .. and I think the correct vote could be given to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery, you can story it in the "data"
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did not know jQuery had that. But this is for my own library so I can't really use that :) thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

No, actually that should work just fine. From what I understand, adding that return to the object should be fine. It's better than storing it in a global container IMO.